# How to get rows by max(date) group by Year-Month in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, aggregation

I am working on migrating a report from MySQL to Postgres and I am trying to get the latest records per each category group by Year and Month, in MySQL it looks like this:

```
 select Category,
        max(DATECOL) AS Date
 from Table
 group by Category, date_format(DATECOL,'%Y-%m')
 order by DATECOL desc;

+----------+------------+
| Category | Date       |
+----------+------------+
| A        | 2021-05-27 |
+----------+------------+
| B        | 2021-05-27 |
+----------+------------+
| A        | 2021-04-30 |
+----------+------------+
| B        | 2021-04-30 |
+----------+------------+
| A        | 2021-03-31 |
+----------+------------+
| B        | 2021-03-31 |
+----------+------------+
```

But When I try the following in Postgres it gives me a `"Must include DATECOL in GROUP BY"` error message and when I include DATECOL it just returns every possible dates. Is there a way to get the max records per category in Postgres? . Here is what I had tried in Postgres which returns the `"Must include DATECOL in GROUP BY"` error

```
 select Category,
        max(DATECOL) AS DATE
 from Table
 group by Category, concat(EXTRACT(year from DATECOL),'-', EXTRACT(month from DATECOL) )
 order by DATECOL desc;
```

Comment: No that did not work in MySQL as it simply returned random results rather than rejecting the invalid query.

Answer (score 3):

To get the latest date per category *and* month, simply group by both. Use  [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to format any way you like:

```
SELECT category
     , to_char(datecol, 'YYYY-MM') AS mon
     , max(datecol) AS max_date
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 2, 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 1;
```

`mon` does not have to be in the `SELECT` list. But then you cannot use ordinal positions as shorthand, of course:

```
SELECT category
     , max(datecol) AS max_date
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY to_char(datecol, 'YYYY-MM'), category
ORDER  BY to_char(datecol, 'YYYY-MM') DESC, category;
```

Downside: formatted text may not sort right (YYYY-MM is typically no problem, of course). And for big tables, [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) is a bit cheaper. And since we are not even displaying it:

```
SELECT category
     , max(datecol) AS max_date
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', datecol), 1
ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', datecol) DESC, 1;
```

To display and format any way you like:

```
SELECT category
     , to_char(date_trunc('month', datecol), 'YYYY-MM') AS mon
     , max(datecol) AS max_date
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', datecol), category
ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', datecol) DESC, category;
```

You have to repeat the `GROUP BY` expression (unless you push it into a subquery), even if that makes no difference for `to_char()`.

Related:

- [Sorting months while im converting them to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105667/sorting-months-while-im-converting-them-to-text/13106152#13106152)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group), is to use window functions: Postgres you

```
select category, 
       DateCol 
from (
  select category, 
         DateCol,
         row_number() over (partition by category, date_trunc('month', DateCol ) 
                            order by DateCol desc) as rn
  from table
) t
where rn = 1;
```